# Difference in chromatic number between Schreier coset graphs and Cayley graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, cayley-graphs

Can the [Schreier coset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier_coset_graph) graphs can be seen as a subgraph of Cayley graph on the same groups(neglecting the loop edges) and, hence, have their chromatic numbers bounded by the chromatic numbers of the Cayley graphs on those groups with the same generating set?

Also, how much does the cardinality of the subgroup determine the gap between the chromatic number of schreier coset graphs and the Cayley graphs on those same groups with the same generating set. Like, if the subgroup with respect to which the cosets are taken is large, then is the gap between the chromatic numbers also proportionally large?  Thanks beforehand.

Comment: If the subgroup is large, say the entire group, then the coset graph will have one vertex and chromatic number 1, which probably is not useful to you.

Comment: @GordonRoyle so then, it seems the gap is sort of directly proportional to the cardinality of the subgroup

Comment: Could you clarify two things.
1) In what sense is the Schreier coset graph a subgraph of Cayley graph? These graphs have different sets of vertices.
2) The coset graph can have loops. How can we define the chromatic number in this case.

Comment: @kabenyuk I hope the set of vertices of Coset graphs are actually a subset of the set of vertices of Cayley graph. If we exclude the identity element in the generating set of the graph, we actually can avoid loops, right?

Comment: @vidyarthi 
This is incorrect. If $G$ is a group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $S$ is a symmetric generating set of $G$ that does not contain the identity element, then the set of vertices of the Cayley graph $\operatorname{Cey}(G,S)$ is $G$, and the set of vertices of cosets graph $\operatorname{Cey}(G/H,S)$ is the set cosets

$$
G/H=\{Hx\mid x\in G\}. 
$$
Well, the graph $\operatorname{Cey}(G/H,S)$ may have loops in spite of the fact that $S$ contains no the identity element.
Take $G=S_3$, $H=\operatorname{gr}(123)$, $S=\{(123),(12)\}$.

Comment: @kabenyuk Thanks, I got your point.

Comment: @kabenyuk what if we neglect the loop edges? Can we prove that the coset graphs are subgraphs of Cayley graphs on the same generating set now. And, by the way, your $S$ missed the element $(132)$ to make it symmetric

Comment: @vidyarthi the Schreier graph is not a subgraph of the Cayley graph. Take $G= C_{3n}$ (cyclic groups on $3n$ elements). Let $S$ be a generator of this cyclic group, then $Cay(G,S)$ is a $3n$-cycle (in particular it contains no 3-cycles for $n>1$. There is a [normal] subgroup $H$ in $G$ which is isomorphic to $C_n$. Then $G/H \cong C_3$. So $Sch(G/H,S)$ is $Cay(G/H,S)$ which is a 3-cycle. You could also do this by replacing $3$ with an arbitrary integer $k>2$.

Comment: @ARG Thanks, so your example shows that the schreier coset graph may have chromatic number beyond that of the cayley graph on the same generating set

Comment: @vidyarthi yes, if one applies it to $C_{kn}$ with $k$ odd and $n$ even, then $C_{kn}/C_{n} \cong C_k$ so that the chromatic of the $C_{kn}$ is 2 while that of the $C_k$ is 3. There are probably many other examples. Also the ratio $kn/n = k$ so that it could be as large as you want (or stay by 3, while $nk \to \infty$).

Comment: @ARG you could write down your comments as an answer which might be good.

Comment: @ARG so if the subgroup is normal, there will be no loops right, but what happened in the previous example of kabenyuk?

Comment: @vidyarthi I posted an answer, as requested. The Schreier graph of $G/H$ will definitively have loops when the subgroup $H$ contains elements of the generating set. More generally, there is a loop if there is a $s \in S$ so that $Hxs = Hx$. This is $\iff H xsx^{-1} = H \iff xsx^{-1} \in H$. In other words, a Schreier graph will have loops iff the subgroup $H$ intersect the conjugacy classes of the generating set.

Comment: By the way I just notices that the discussion above uses the notation $G/H$ while the cosets in the Schreier graph are $Hx$. I think you should write the cosets as $xH$ (if you are using $G/H$) or write the quotient as $H \backslash G$ (if you are using the cosets $Hx$)

Comment: @vidyarthi when the subgroup H is normal, this only means that the Schreier graph will just be the same as a Cayley graph. In particular it will be vertex-transitive. This is not the case for generic Schreier graphs (in fact almost any regular graph is a Schreier graph, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287720/which-3-regular-graphs-are-schreier-coset-graphs) for some infos.

Comment: @ARG thanks! When is it the case that a Schreier coset graph is not even vertex transitive?

Comment: @vidyarthi I'm not sure what is the group-theoretic condition on $G$ and $H$ so that the corresponding graph is vertex-transitive. Perhaps there is something about the nomraliser and/or the automorphisms of $G$ (or automorphisms of $G$ fixing $H$). That might be an interesting question. I would post it, but please do so first if you wish.

Comment: said question has been posted [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418122/when-is-a-schreier-coset-graph-vertex-transitive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good example.

Let $G=S_n$, $S=\{(i,j)\mid 1\leq i<j\leq n \}$. Then $\operatorname{Cay}(G,S)$ is a bipartite graph and so its chromatic number is $2$. Let $H=\{g\in S_n\mid g(n)=n\}$. It is easy to check that $\operatorname{Sch}(G/H,S)$ is a complete graph (if we forget about loops) and hence its chromatic number is $n$.

Answer (score 1):

As requested by the OP, here is a simple example of the fact that the chromatic number may go up, and that the Schreier graph is not a subgraph of the Cayley graph.

Let $k>2$ be odd and $n>1$ be even. Let $G = C_{kn}$ (the cyclic groups on $kn$  elements, it is $\cong \mathbb{Z}/kn\mathbb{Z}$).
Let $S = \lbrace -1, 1\rbrace$ be a [symmetric] generating set of this cyclic group.
Then $\mathrm{Cay}(G,S)$ is a cycle of length $kn$ (in particular it contains no odd cycles, since $n>1$).
There is a [normal] subgroup $H$ in $G$ which is isomorphic to $C_n$ (this is the subgroup generated by $k \in \mathbb{Z}$).
It is fairly standard exercise to check that $G/H \cong C_k$.
By normality $\mathrm{Sch}(G/H,S)$ is isomorphic $\mathrm{Cay}(G/H,S)$ which itself is a cycle of length $k$.

The Schreier Graph $\mathrm{Sch}(G/H,S)$, being an odd cycle, has chromatic number 3 and is not isomorphic to any subgraph of $\mathrm{Cay}(G,S)$ (which is an even cycle with chromatic number 2).

Furthermore, by fixing $k$ an letting $n \to \infty$, the ratio $\frac{\# \text{Vertices of } \mathrm{Cay}(G,S)}{\#\text{Vertices of } \mathrm{Sch}(G/H,S)}$ tends to infinity. By fixing $n$ and letting $k \to \infty$, the ratio remains constant, while the cardinalities tend to infinity.